# Merge two flat associative arrays and sum the values of shared keys

Tags: php, arrays, sum, associative-array, merging-data

I have two arrays :

```
$A = array("EUR" => 10, "USD" => 20)
$B = array("EUR" => 10, "JPY" => 20)
```

I want to merge and sum the the value which have the same keys.

```
$C = array(
    "EUR" => 20, // array(10, 10),
    "JPY" => 20,
    "USD" => 20,
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this code:

```
<?php
$A = array("EUR"=>10,"USD"=>20);
$B = array("EUR"=>10,"JPY"=>20);

$C = $A;
foreach ($B as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($C[$key])) {
        $C[$key] = $C[$key] + $value;
    } else {
        $C[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

the result will be the following array:

```
array(3) {
  ["EUR"] => int(20)
  ["USD"] => int(20)
  ["JPY"] => int(20)
}
```

It already calculates the sum. For proof look at http://codepad.org/Aay0bEh9.

If you do want the entry for EUR in the resulting array $C to be an array(10, 10) you can change the body of the foreach loop into the following code:

```
if (! isset($C[$key])) {
    $C[$key] = array();
}
$C[$key][] = $value;
```

**EDIT:**

For my last remark and code sample, instead of changing the body of the foreach you can simply do the following:

```
$C = array_merge_recursive($A, $B);
```

Comment: The second option will set an array(10, 10) for the EUR key in the $C array. I know this is not a total for the EUR currency, but it is equal to the result you ask for in your question :) That's why I included it in my answer.

Comment: I posted another answer in your new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760320/write-code-manually-instead-of-using-array-merge-recusive-in-php.

Answer (score 0):

Save the first array as the initial data of the result array.
Then loop over the second array and add the current value to either the pre-existing key's value or 0.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Z2XJ5))

```
$A = ["EUR" => 10, "USD" => 20];
$B = ["EUR" => 10, "JPY" => 20];

$result = $A;
foreach ($B as $k => $v) {
    $result[$k] = ($result[$k] ?? 0) + $v;
}
var_export($result);
```