# What PHP code emulates the behaviour of array_merge_recusive?

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to do something like instead of using array_merge_recusive in php

```
<?php
$A = array("EUR"=>10);
$B = array("EUR"=>10,"JPY"=>20);    
$C = $A;
foreach ($B as $key => $value) {
    if (!isset($C[$key])) {
        $C[$key][] = array();
    } 
     $C[$key] = $value;

}

var_dump($C);

array(2) {
  ["EUR"]=>
  int(10)
  ["JPY"]=>
  int(20)
}
```

I need to get like this:

```
array(2) {
  ["EUR"]=>array(10,10),
  ["JPY"]=> int(20)
}
```

EDIT

Check code I am trying here http://codepad.org/x4MuYCiH
What I did wrong ,I could not get the expected result?

thanks

Comment: Is there any reason, why you don't use *array\_merge\_recursive*, when it produces the output, you want?

Comment: @harald Good question. My answer below emulates the array_merge_recursive() function, but I do not understand why someone would want that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the solution see this paste: http://codepad.org/60IKweVu. I also show the code at the bottom of this answer. This solution is based on the example data in your previous question about this [array merge and total if it the same keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7756593/array-merge-and-total-if-it-the-same-keys).

Note that

```
array(2) {
  ["EUR"]=>array(10,10),
  ["JPY"]=> int(20)
}
```

is equivalent to

```
array(2) {
  ["EUR"]=> array([0] => 10, [1] => 10),
  ["JPY"]=> int(20)
}
```

but that the first notation simply does not show the keys of the nested array.

**CODE**:

```
<?php
$A = array("EUR"=>10,"USD"=>20);
$B = array("EUR"=>10,"JPY"=>20);

$C = array_merge_recursive($A, $B);
var_dump($C);

//
// This emulates the array_merge_recursive call
//
$C = array();
$allArrays = array($A, $B);
foreach($allArrays as $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (! isset($C[$key])) {
            $C[$key] = array();
        }
        $C[$key][] = $value;
    }
}

foreach ($C as $index => $values) {
    if (count($values) == 1) {
        $C[$index] = $values[0];
    }
}

var_dump($C);
```

Comment: BTW this code adds the arrays $A and $B to another array $allArrays, this will make it easier to use the code if you have more arrays than the $A and $B arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This is the right code:

```
foreach ($B as $key => $value) {
    if (! isset($C[$key]) )
       $C[$key] = $value;
    else
    {
       if (isset($C[$key]) && !is_array($C[$key]) )
          $C[$key] = array($C[$key]);
       $C[$key][] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: every your elements are array.in fact in not what I want.like you see if EUR in both $A and $ B so will be a array of it,other wise it is normal value, Anywhere thank for your code.

Comment: If you run $C = array_merge_recursive($A, $B);
 will see what the result I want to got.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an empty second level array with

```
$C[$key][] = array();
```

which then you overwrite with a single value in

```
$C[$key] = $value;
```

Hope this is hint enough...

Comment: I am still not understand the problem here.could you give more clear.